# Can't call integer from array

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to save a highscore from an array but this line won't work.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScores[x] forKey:@"HighScore%iSaved", x];
```

I keep getting the error 'Too many arguments to method call, expected 2, have 3'
How do I fix this so it will save the specific HighScore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your key.You need formatted string. Change it with the code below.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScores[x] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore%iSaved", x]];
```